# MongoDB is extremely slow when using count() on array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance

**Introduction**

My collection has more than 1 million of documents. Each document's structure is identical and looks like this:

```
{_id: "LiTC4psuoLWokMPmY", number: "12345", letter: "A", extra: [{eid:"jAHBSzCeK4SS9bShT", value: "Some text"}]}
```

So, as you can see, my `extra` field is an array that contains small objects. I'm trying to insert these objects as many as possible (until I get closer to 16MB of document limit). And these objects usually present in the `extra` array of the most documents in the collections. So I usually have hundreds of thousands of the same objects.

I have an index on `eid` key in the `extra` array. I created this index by using this:

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({"extra.eid":1})
```

**Problem**

I want to count how many `extra` field object present in the collection. I'm doing it by using this:

```
db.collectionName.find({extra: {eid: "jAHBSzCeK4SS9bShT"}}).count()
```

In the beginning, the query above is very fast. But whenever `extra` array gets a little bit bigger (more than 20 objects), it gets really slow.

With 3-4 objects, it takes less than 100 miliseconds but when it gets bigger, it takes a lot more time. With 50 objects, it takes 6238 miliseconds.

**Questions**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I make this process faster?
3. Is there any other way that does this process but faster?

Comment: Consider creating an index for "extra" as well.

Comment: @FelipeSulser Unfortunately, that's not possible because index key is too large.

Comment: Does using aggregation work any faster, as I don't think using a find and count is the right way to go. For example

db.collectionName.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$extra.eid", count: {$sum:1}}});

Comment: @WhiteBullet Aggregation is faster than find and count but not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941593/mongodb-indexes-on-subdocuments-not-being-used-based-on-syntax-of-query). I bet your query isn't hitting your index.

You can do an explain (run `db.collectionName.find({extra: {eid: "jAHBSzCeK4SS9bShT"}}).explain()` in the Mongo shell) to know for sure.

The reason is that in Mongo `db.collectionName.find({extra: {eid: "jAHBSzCeK4SS9bShT"}})` is not the same as `db.collectionName.find({"extra.eid": "jAHBSzCeK4SS9bShT"})`. The first form won't use your index, while the second form will (as an example, although this wouldn't work in your case because your subdocument is actually an array). Not sure why, but this seems to be a quirk of Mongo's query builder.

I didn't find any solution except for indexing the entire subdocument.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Thanks a lot! The second query is twice as fast. And you were right, first one is not using the index. You said second query wouldn't work for me; but it works. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's great if it works! I just wasn't sure because I've only used that syntax on subdocuments that weren't arrays. Just to be sure, you can run `explain()` on it and ensure it's using the index. Glad it's running faster :-) FWIW, I'm still not sure if this behavior is intended or a bug...

Comment: It works really well! Yeah, I used `explain()` to check index usage and only the second one showed that it was being used. I redesigned the `extra` field, it contains more complex objects now. I inserted 70 objects for each document and with the first query (not using index), count took 7357 milliseconds where with the second query (using index), count took only 104 milliseconds.

I hope this isn't a bug :)

Thanks a lot again!